# Correct Effective Bandwith calculations of y = Ax+b?

Tags: cuda

I would like to calculate the bandwith of 
the matrix vector multiplication and addition: (assume A = M times N big)
y = A*x +b

But I am a bit confused about what read and write count to the number of bytes read from global memory:

is the effective bandwith:

```
bytesReadWrite = M*N (for reading A) + N(for read x) + M (for read b)  + M(for write y)
```

or is it

```
bytesReadWrite = M*N (for reading A) + M*N (for read x) + M (for read b)  + M(for write y)
```

M*N for x because we read once the whole x for each row basically (also if we work with shared memory, we have eventually read once the whole x vector per row)

Does somebody have some good advice of what is the right choice? I dont get this really...

I tend to use the first calculation but why? Does it make sense?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: OK, the correct an the most meaningful effectiv bandwith calculation is  the first one, as it includes the minimal effort to complete the matrix vector multiplication...

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly none of the above.  In terms of memory bandwidth, modern processors will load all of the items to be operated on once into Level 2 cache, and operate on them from there, after which the results will be written back out to memory for any items changed.  Effectively, your bandwidth is just the sum total size for all of the elements involved.  Note: even this is an oversimplification, because it doesn't take into account the effects of streaming, not to mention memory pagination.  For streaming, it's not uncommon to have a single matrix operate on a large set of data (3D graphics calculations, for example); in that case, the matrix gets loaded to L2 cache (and presumably for reasonably optimized code into the registers from there) once, and then the vectors get loaded through.  Once again, the model isn't really complete without an understanding of modern memory paging techniques; there's a gigantic difference in the above if the matrix and the vectors are stored in different memory pages, for example; not to mention serious optimizations in packing vectors together for "streaming" into L2 cache.  And even then, that's assuming a CPU model of performing the matrix math; bringing a GPU into the picture changes things once again very dramatically.

Comment: I tried to follow the CUDA GUID, which describes the thing as my question above, I understand that I cannot include L2 caches and other stuff happening, its supposed to be the "effective" bandwith everything talks about and what should be optimized according to the CUDA Guide... hm...